# Is there a way to find a .png template into a screenshot I took with pyautogui?

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui, game-automation

So I have 44 perflectly crop template with no background and mi goal is to see if one of the template is on a screenshot took with pyautogui. mi only problem is that I dont have any idea of how to do this. And the template on the screenshot can be oriented in anyway (but still a 2d object so its just a matter of rotation) + the template dont have the same size as on the screen.

here is how I tried to do it using opencv using only 1 image that was present on screen:

```
import cv2
import pyautogui
import numpy as np

objet_image = cv2.imread('traps/canon\\Cannon1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

objet_image = cv2.cvtColor(objet_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

if objet_image.shape[2] > 1:
    objet_image = cv2.cvtColor(objet_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot, objet_image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

objet_position = max_loc

pyautogui.moveTo(objet_position[0], objet_position[1])
```

I converted the image in 8bits because I got prompt of error with depth:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\autre\Documents\VsCode\King of Thieves bot\test.py", line 16, in <module>
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot, objet_image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1164: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you may have to generate images with different rotations and different sizes and compare it with templates.

Comment: [OpenCV Template Matching ( cv2.matchTemplate ) - PyImageSearch](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/22/opencv-template-matching-cv2-matchtemplate/)

Comment: you may also ask on official [forum OpenCV](https://forum.opencv.org/)

Comment: Why do u had slash and backslash in `cv2.imread`?

Comment: the cv2.matchtemplate won't work cuz img realy aint the same everytime and creating others template to compare would take too long. I thing am going to train a CNN on recognizing, I can get as much example as I want. and it would help me on simplifying the work

Comment: pictures please.